# How to add static date to a time in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have shifting schedules which I wanted to add a date.

Example:
8am - 5pm EST ---> 04/02/22 8am - 04/02/22 5pm

and

4pm - 1am EST ---> 04/02/22 4pm - 04/03/22 1am

I can easily add the date in the morning shift but I am having problem with the Overnight Shift.

Sample sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b7scPS7y_43r5KlUKsafiHqq6dCgVg25ZUQzU3hEJyw/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Hi. Here's the sample sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b7scPS7y_43r5KlUKsafiHqq6dCgVg25ZUQzU3hEJyw/edit?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 1):

you could add dates in a column (for example E column) and then use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E="",,TEXT({E2:E+B2:B, IF((REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(B2:B), "PM"))*
 REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(C2:C), "AM"), E2:E+1+B2:B, E2:E+B2:B)}, "mm/dd/yy hh:mm AM/PM")))
```

[image]